# Cordova/Phonegap: Untrusted certificate crashes on navigator.app.exitApp()

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

I've submitted a patch to hypery2k's untrusted certificate plugin that allows it to run in the latest version of Cordova, but I've run into another one that I can't seem to figure out. For reference, the issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/hypery2k/cordova-certificate-plugin/issues/3

**Symptoms:**

This works, and after about 10 seconds the app exits cleanly (this is just for demonstration):

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    init();
    setTimeout(function() { navigator.app.exitApp(); }, 10000);
},
```

However, this crashes and pops up the "quit unexpectedly" message in Android:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    init();
    cordova.plugins.certificates.trustUnsecureCerts(true);
    setTimeout(function() { navigator.app.exitApp(); }, 10000);
},
```

With this in the logcat:

```
D/CordovaActivity( 2561): onMessage(exit,null)
D/CordovaActivity( 2561): Paused the application!
W/PluginManager( 2561): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to App.exitApp blocked the main thread for 90ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
D/CordovaActivity( 2561): CordovaActivity.onDestroy()
D/CordovaWebView( 2561): >>> loadUrlNow()
D/CordovaWebViewClient( 2561): onPageFinished(about:blank)
D/AndroidRuntime( 2561): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 2561): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0d58b20)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2561): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 2561): Process: com.mycomp.myapp, PID: 2561
E/AndroidRuntime( 2561): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 2561):        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.onPageFinished(CordovaWebViewClient.java:215)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2561):        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onPageFinished(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:449)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2561):        at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClient$AwWebContentsObserver$1.run(AwContentsClient.java:73)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2561):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2561):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2561):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2561):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2561):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2561):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2561):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2561):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2561):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/Process ( 2561): Sending signal. PID: 2561 SIG: 9
I/ActivityManager( 1276): Process com.mycomp.myapp (pid 2561) has died.
```

Everything else works fine, it just crashes when you try to implement code to exit the application, such as on back button press.

This is the main block of code that runs from the plugin when the above trustUnsecureCerts function is called:

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args,
        CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

    if (action.equals("setUntrusted")) {
            allowUntrusted = args.getBoolean(0);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Setting allowUntrusted to " + allowUntrusted);
            cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                            CertificatesCordovaWebViewClient cWebClient = new CertificatesCordovaWebViewClient(cordova);
                            cWebClient.setAllowUntrusted(allowUntrusted);
                            webView.setWebViewClient(cWebClient);
                            CordovaActivity ca = (CordovaActivity) cordova.getActivity();
                            ca.clearCache();
                    }
            });
            callbackContext.success();
            return true;
    }
    callbackContext.error("Invalid Command");
    return false;
}
```

And if it helps to see the entire class definition, the two full source files can be found here: https://github.com/hypery2k/cordova-certificate-plugin/tree/master/src/android/de/martinreinhardt/cordova/plugins

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: why do you want to close your app just after 1 second? I think the problem is the plugins are async, so you app.exitApp() might be executing before the plugin finish it's work and the code is still executed but crash. Try with a bigger timeout

Comment: No, sorry, that's just demonstration. Even after minutes, calling exitApp() crashes. I've updated the code, but it is merely demonstration, no matter where I put the call (such as on back button press from the home screen) it bombs. My intent is to be able to exit the app with the back button.